# Событие клика после перехода по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы при переходе по ссылке внутри сайта на странице на которую я перешел произошел клик по элементу с определенным id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика может быть такой:

1. В ссылку зашиваете якорь или utm-метку (разницы нет - просто любую дополнительную информацию, которая понадобится при обработке)

   `<a href="/newpage#forclick">Ссылка на страницу</a>`
2. На странице, куда осуществлён переход, получаете window.location.href и проверяете, есть ли там #forclick. Если есть, делаете клик. Если нет (то есть на эту страницу перешли не по ссылке), ничего не делаете.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш JS не работает на новой странице, после перехода (это не безопасно).

В любом случае нельзя инициализировать полноценный клик программно (это не безопасно).

Если бы можно было взаимодействовать с чужими страницами, или инициализировать клики на них, любой администратор мог бы взаимодействовать, например с вашим онлайн банком.

Но если переход будет на страницу вашего сайта, то что мешает там заново выполнить любой скрипт, в том числе действия, которые должны произойти после нажатия на элемент с определенным id?

Answer (score 0):

По сути, не имеет значение, был переход на внутри сайта или нет - на своем сайте Вы можете выполнить клик в любой удобный для Вас момент.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('forclick');
elem.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.type);
});
const myEvent = new Event('click');
setTimeout(() => {
  elem.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="forclick"></div>
```